# getExternalStorageState IN eCLIPSE ISSUE

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

On eclipse, the emulator returns `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` as removed and path as /mnt/sdcard... How do I mount the memory back? Earlier the same was read only i.e /mnt/sdcard had permission `d---------` which i changed using `chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your AVD in the AVD manager..remove SDcard Support and add again and allocate memory ..check if it works??

Comment: no that didnt work and i get the following error now ...
 Please ensure that adb is correctly located at "C..."